# Answer a question in a command line program

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

Im running a program called `CTB.exe`, and it has a list of `5` options that we can do. I want a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to run the program, and always answer `3` for the list to continue the program. I'm new to this and can't figure it out.

I tried this in my bat file:

```
CTB.exe
echo 3 | CTB.exe

CTB.exe
echo 3 | CTB.exe
```

It would answer `3` when I start the `.bat` file. It doesn't.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have removed your [[tag:DOS]] tag along with the [[tag:CMD]] tag. If the intention was to have this work in DOS instead of a modern Windows Operating System, please feel free to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56792380/edit), to tell us which version of DOS you want this for, and re-add the [[tag:DOS]] tag.

Comment: Hard to tell as long as you don't tell us what `CTB.exe` is and how it expects the option selection; does it prompt you, or does it expect command line arguments? is it capable of reading _STDIN_? can it read options from some configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

```
CTB.exe
echo 3 | CTB.exe
```

will first start `CTB.exe`. When it that is finished running, it will then start `CTB.exe` again, but this time with `3` piped to its standard input.

So if `CTB.exe` reads the user's selection of "options that we can do" from standard input, then the correct solution to always enter 3 is just `echo 3 | CTB.exe`. And if itobtains its input in a different way, you will have to provide it in a corresponding way.

Comment: It seems that bad formatting of the original question led you to the assumption that `CTB.exe` is in the same line as `echo 3 | CTB.exe`, but it seems this is not the case...